# React Native show Dialog or Popup in catch error handler

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am very new to React Native and try to show a popup if an error ist throwen. But I dont get it to work. Thats my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Alert, Modal, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import { Text } from 'react-native-paper'
import Background from '../components/Background'
import Logo from '../components/Logo'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Button from '../components/Button'
import TextInput from '../components/TextInput'
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton'
import { theme } from '../core/theme'
import { emailValidator } from '../helpers/emailValidator'
import { passwordValidator } from '../helpers/passwordValidator'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';


export default function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState({ value: '', error: '' })
  const [password, setPassword] = useState({ value: '', error: '' })
  const [hidePass, setHidePass] = useState(true);
  const onLoginPressed = () => {
  const emailError = emailValidator(email.value)
  const passwordError = passwordValidator(password.value)
  
  

 
   
    
    if (emailError || passwordError) {
    
      setEmail({ ...email, error: emailError })
      setPassword({ ...password, error: passwordError })
      return

    }else{
        

const SignUp = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://www.ecample.com/endpoint', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: email.value,
          password: password.value
        })
      })
      let json = await response.json()
      if ((typeof json.token !== 'undefined') && (json.token.length > 230)) {

        alert('fdgdg')

      } else {
        navigation.reset({
          index: 0,
          routes: [{ name: 'ErrorPage' }],
        })
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
            return (
                <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                  <Modal
                    animationType="slide"
                    transparent={true}
                    visible={modalVisible}
                    onRequestClose={() => {
                      Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
                      setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                    }}
                  >
                    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                      <View style={styles.modalView}>
                        <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>
                        <Pressable
                          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
                          onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
                        >
                          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
                        </Pressable>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  </Modal>
                  <Pressable
                    style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOpen]}
                    onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Show Modal</Text>
                  </Pressable>
                </View>
              );
    }

  }     

    } // ende else
  }

  
  
  
  return (

      
      
      
    <Background>
  
      <BackButton goBack={navigation.goBack} />
      <Logo />
      <Header>Bitte geben Sie Ihre Daten ein.</Header> 
      
      <TextInput
        label="E-Mail"
        returnKeyType="next"
        value={email.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail({ value: text, error: '' })}
        error={!!email.error}
        errorText={email.error}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCompleteType="email"
        textContentType="emailAddress"
        keyboardType="email-address"
      />    
            
    
      <TextInput 
        label="Passwort"
        returnKeyType="done"
        value={password.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword({ value: text, error: '' })}
        error={!!password.error}
        errorText={password.error}
       secureTextEntry={hidePass ? true : false}
      />
        <Icon style={styles.eyeContainer}
              name={hidePass ? 'eye-slash' : 'eye'}
              size={15}
              color="grey"
              onPress={() => setHidePass(!hidePass)}
            />    

      <View style={styles.forgotPassword}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ResetPasswordScreen')}
        >
          <Text style={styles.forgot}>Passwort vergessen?</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>


      <Button color="#1584a5" mode="contained" onPress={onLoginPressed}>
        Login
      </Button>
          
          
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text>Keinen Account? </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.replace('RegisterScreen')}>
          <Text style={styles.link}>Jetzt registrieren</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
          
    </Background>
         
  )
}
```

I tried different modules and scripts but I cant get a popup. The endpoint works fine. I receive a token, an error 403 or an html with 503 as answer. Therefore I used the catch error.

I nearly tried every Modal, Popup, Alert which I could find in the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  const SignUp = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/endpoint', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: email.value,
          password: password.value
        })
      })
      if (response.status === 200) {
        let json = await response.json()
        if ((typeof json.token !== 'undefined') && (json.token.length > 230)) {
          alert('fdgdg')

        } else {
          navigation.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [{ name: 'ErrorPage' }],
          })
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error(`failed due to status code ${response.status}`);

      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      // write code to open modal here
      //openErrorModal(err)
    }

  }
```

Comment: Hello dheeraj, thank you for the code but it is not working. I updated my code from above for the Loginscreen  what did I miss??

Comment: Are you having any errors. once check your node/metro bundler since we are using catch error will be displayed in logs

Comment: no, nothing happens. Also the console says no error.

Comment: How do I have to call the const SignUp in the else clause? Sorry I am realy new to this.

Comment: if(false){
}else{
SignUp();
}

Comment: ok now the endpoint answers with a html file with error 503. And I think the code cant handle this error: The error I receive is JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: modalVisible]

Comment: i have updated code to handle the status you can check with it

Comment: The html error is handled now but modal popup doesent work :(( No error is in the  console and no popup shows up.

Comment: i have just seen complete code you have updated you are missing modalVisible state and  thats not how u call singup so i have formatted the code you can check it here :https://snack.expo.dev/M1R770Lzj

Comment: YOU ARE PERFECT! I I have a last question: How can I handle multiple popups? Can I create a separate file and call the needed modal popup than? How does it work?

Comment: yes you can make a component out of it and use as you like.
provided you a sample how i use https://snack.expo.dev/YjJnYE7uz

Comment: Perfect this worked now.

Comment: I discoverd one failure now. The Response of the fetch is always 503. Just if the login is correct it is 200. Normaly if the Username is correct but the pssword is wrong, the response error should be 403 but this is not working? In Postmann everything works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Alert component from react-native.

```
fetchEvents() {
   fetch('http://www.wrongurl.com', {
     method: 'GET',
     redirect: 'follow'
   })
   .then(function(response) {
       if (response.status == 200) {
           let responseText = JSON.stringify(response.text());
           console.log(responseText);
       }
     else throw new Error('HTTP response status not code 200 as expected.');
   })
    .catch(function(error) {
       Alert.alert(error);   // Using this line
   });
}
```